# Powershell - Getting a random folder is not working

Tags: powershell

i want to open a random folder on my E-Disk. I've tried so many things, but it just wont work..
If I run the script, nothing happens, but the script is running endlessly. What can I do differently?

This is my code:

```
$efestplatte = 'E:\'
$ordnerListe = Get-ChildItem -Path $efestplatte -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
$zufälligerIndex = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $ordnerListe.Count
$zufälligerOrdner = $ordnerListe[$zufälligerIndex]
Invoke-Item $zufälligerOrdner.FullName
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: like dis? `gci -dir -Recurse | Get-Random | % { start $_.FullName }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe items to `Get-Random` to get a random directory, similarly, you can also pipe items to `Inoke-Item` to invoke them.

So your code can be simplified to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $efestplatte -Directory -Recurse |
    Get-Random |
    Invoke-Item
```

Filtering for `.PSIsContainer` with `Where-Object` is also irrelevant. This filtering is already ensured at the moment you used the `-Directory` switch.

If you want to store the randomly picked folder you can first assign it to a variable then invoke it...

```
$randomFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $efestplatte -Directory -Recurse |
    Get-Random
$randomFolder | Invoke-Item
```